# click a image to redirect to a defined url

Tags: javascript

I want to click on a image and redirect to a url that has the subdomain $platform and filter $search_filter. This is what i have so far. Help please?

```
<head>
<script>      
  function search_platform() {
    var $platform=document.getElementById("search_platform").value;
    var $search_filter=document.getElementById("search_filter").value;
    if ($platform !== '0') {
      document.location.href='http://www.' + $platform + 'domain.com/index.php?filter_name=' + $search_filter;
    }
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>

  <select id="search_platform">
    <option value="0" selected="selected"><?php echo 'Select Platform'; ?></option>
    <option value="platform1">Platform 1</option>
    <option value="platform1">Platform 1</option>
    <option value="platform1">Platform 1</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" name="filter_name"/>
  <img src="test.png" width="264" height="110"  onclick="search_platform()"/>

</body>
```

Comment: Nothing is happening. I figured i must be missing something?

Comment: search_filter do not exists, maybe use filter_name? add id to control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
    <head>
    <script>      
      function search_platform() {
       //Removed $ from variables name
        var platform=document.getElementById("search_platform").value;
        var search_filter=document.getElementById("search_filter").value;
        if (platform !== '0') {
          document.location.href='http://www.' + platform + 'domain.com/index.php?filter_name=' + search_filter;
        }
      }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

      <select id="search_platform">
        <option value="0" selected="selected"><?php echo 'Select Platform'; ?></option>
        <option value="platform1">Platform 1</option>
        <option value="platform1">Platform 1</option>
        <option value="platform1">Platform 1</option>
      </select>
      <input type="text" name="filter_name" id="search_filter"/> <!-- Added id -->
      <img src="test.png" width="264" height="110"  onclick="search_platform()"/>

    </body>
```

Comment: Great! I'm glad you have been helpful :) .

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the ID in the input field:

```
<input type="text" name="filter_name" id="search_filter"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is getting value from select element. try below

```
<script>      
  function search_platform() {
    var $platform=document.getElementById("search_platform").value;
    var $selectedplatform = platform.options[platform.selectedIndex].value;
    var $search_filter=document.getElementById("search_filter").value;
    if ($platform !== '0') {
      document.location.href='http://www.' + $selectedplatform + 'domain.com/index.php?filter_name=' + $search_filter;
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I try to modify all your code to make it more standard.

```
<head>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      function search_platform() {
         var platform=document.getElementById("search_platform").value;
         var search_filter=document.getElementById("search_filter").value;
         if (platform !== '0') {
            document.location.href='http://www.' + platform + '.domain.com/index.php?filter_name=' + search_filter;                                                                        
         }
      }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
   <select id="search_platform">
      <option value="0" selected="selected"><?php echo 'Select Platform'; ?></option>
      <option value="1mmtform1">Platform 1</option>
      <option value="platform2">Platform 2</option>
      <option value="platform3">Platform 3</option>
   </select>
   <input type="text" name="filter_name" id="search_filter"/>
   <img src="test.png" width="264" height="110" onclick="javascript:search_platform()" />
 </body>
```